# Minimum bounding geometry with "group" option gives error in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, error-999999

The minimum bounding geometry tool is working fine on my data, but when I try using the "group" option, I get `ERROR 999999: Error executing function.`

I would like generate two polygons, A and B, which are the convex hull of their corresponding group of points. This is what the attribute table of my point shapefile looks like:

```
lat  long  ID
Ax1  Ay1   nameA
Ax2  Ay2   nameA
Ax3  Ay3   nameA
Bx1  By1   nameB
Bx2  By2   nameB
Bx3  By3   nameB
```

I can run the MBG (Minimum Bounding Geometry) tool for all the data and get one big polygon. But this isn't what I want; I want individual polygons based on their ID. When I use the "group" function within the MBG tool, I select LIST and my ID column. But the process fails and I get the aforementioned error.

Other details:
I am using ArcMap 10.3.1.
The exact error log is as follows:

Input features

- sheet$ Events
- Geometry Type: Convex Hull
- Group Option: List
- Group Field: ID
- Add geometry characteristics as attributes to output: NO_MBG_FIELDS

Messages:

> ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>
> Failed to execute (MinimumBoundingGeometry)

Comment: Please **edit** the question to explain exactly how you are using a "group" function. You also need to specify what format the source data is in (shapefile, file geodatabase, enterprise geodatabase) and if enterprise GDB, which RDBMS (exact release).  Finally, please specify the exact version of ArcGIS and the *complete* geoprocessing log (the exact command, and all its output)

Comment: Convert event table to true feature class. Repair geometry, try again. One of the group single point?

Comment: @FelixIP Turning this into a feature class in a geodatabase did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As per @FelixIP's comment, this error was fixed by turning my points into a feature class and working within a geodatabase.